# I tried to tag a question with Railties and it won't because Railtie is already used

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I am referring to [Cannot resolve gem dependencies - doorkeeper, sass-rails - on jruby using Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676600/cannot-resolve-gem-dependencies-doorkeeper-sass-rails-on-jruby-using-rails) to a problem with gem dependencies, in particular with the Railties gem versions available.

I should be able to tag the question with Railties, not just Railtie , surely?

The gem in question is, after all, named Railties .  It isn't a question about a Railtie. Anyway, when trying to tag, it suggested I ask the question here.

Comment: So let me get that straight: there's one thing called "Railtie" and another (unrelated?) thing that's called "Railties"?

Comment: The ruby gem is called "railties" - that's what i want to tag - it's a very common gem included in every rails application... if someone got an unfortunately common error with dependencies on railties they'd probably google "railties" as it appears in the terminal, not railtie.  Now there is a thing called a railtie.  Sometimes people will ask question about building their own railties, in which case I can imagine them using the tag railtie.  If you do a search on stack overflow for railtie you'll see more than half the questions are really asking about the Railties gem.

Comment: i.e. if they'd had the choice they'd probably have preferred to tag their question railties, not railtie

Comment: So is this just plain wrong: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html ?

Comment: ?  Not sure what you're asking me there... what are you asking me is wrong about the definitive explanation for the term railtie, which is obviously not wrong? The point I'm asking about is not whether or not the railties gem is related to the railtie functionality in Rails.  It's whether we can have a tag for railties - so we can reference the railties gem, not for railtie the object.

Comment: If you don't want people asking these questions and they're going to be met with hostility and sarcasm why bother having a pop up that says 'ask the question here' with a link when trying to add something?

Comment: Sorry, that my asking came across as sarcasm, it was not intended that way. I just genuinely don't know about those terms and am confused because both "railtie" and "railties" seem to be actual things according to my limited Google-fu, but you say that only one of them is relevant. I'm just trying to combine those two inputs into a meaningful result. Do we need two separate tags? Tag synonyms? I don't know.

Comment: Ok, I think I can grok it now: The Gem ("package") is called "Railties", the main building block in there is a "Railtie". You argue that the tag should be named "Railties" because that's what most people talk about.

Comment: Okay.  Understood.  I don't know if it's what most people talk about.  I just did a quick stack-overflow search for the term railtie and skimming the first 40-50 results you'll see that more than half are referencing railties not railtie - it might seem a pointless difference, and that's fine if there's a policy about not having plural and single versions of the same word as tags, but the railties and railtie questions appear to be of difference character.  So there is a qualitative difference between the two so I just wanted to ask if we could have a railties tag. No is always a valid answer.

Comment: The difference being, for clarity, that most of the questions about railties, the gem, are issues around dependencies, bundler, installation and setup of rails applications.  The railtie questions are more technical questions about code inside an application - so searching for one you probably want to see a different set of answers than the other.  At least when I was searching for answers I found about half the questions were about a particular railtie issue and were unhelpful to my search for answers to dependency problems with versions of the railties gem.  Hope I explained myself better :)

Comment: Might be worth editing some of this additional information about them being two separate, unrelated things into the question. Like Joachim I'm not familiar with Rails and it's not immediately obvious from the question that there should be a distinction between the tags.